# Where can I declare my StringVar to trace it and use it with an OptionBox

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have been trying to declare this StringVar so that when I change the contents of one option box the contents of another one is updated. While this has been asked many times, I cannot seem to make it work.

Usually it is said that you should declare it before the combo box, write the 'update' routine and declare the trace below that on the same line as the 'def'. This worked, however I also want to access the value of my string var in many other routines and so declared it with 'self.' I don't seem to be able to make both things work at once.

Below is some of my code, take note of `self.varRun` and the bottom routine as these are what must work with each other (while still being able to use `varRuns` in other routines in this class).

```
class createViewer(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        leftFrame = Tk.Frame(self)
        leftFrame.pack(side="left")

        botLeftFrame = Tk.Frame(leftFrame)
        botLeftFrame.pack(side="bottom")

        Import = Tk.Button(botLeftFrame)
        Import["text"] = "Import Frame"
        Import["command"] = self.importRun
        Import.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        Load = Tk.Button(botLeftFrame)
        Load["text"] = "Load Frame"
        Load["command"] = self.loadRun
        Load.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        runLabel = Tk.Label(botLeftFrame, text = "Select Run")
        runLabel.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)


        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Public\dbsDetectorBookingSystem.accdb')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        self.Runs = []
        cursor.execute("SELECT RunFilePath FROM tblRuns")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            self.Runs.append(row.RunFilePath)

        self.varRun = Tk.StringVar()
        self.varRun.set("None selected")
        self.varRun.trace('w', self.runSelectionChanged)

        self.SelectRun = Tk.OptionMenu(botLeftFrame, self.varRun, *self.Runs)
        self.SelectRun.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        frameLabel = Tk.Label(botLeftFrame, text = "Select Frame")
        frameLabel.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        self.varFrame = Tk.StringVar()
        self.Frames = ["holder","holder2"]
        self.SelectFrame = Tk.OptionMenu(botLeftFrame, self.varFrame, *self.Frames)
        self.varFrame.set("None selected")
        self.SelectFrame.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        Home = Tk.Button(botLeftFrame, text="Home",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(createHome))
        Home.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)


        topLeftFrame = Tk.Frame(leftFrame)
        topLeftFrame.pack(side="top", expand = True, fill = "both")

        img = Image.open("C:\Users\Jacob\workspace2\Blank2.png")
        blkImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.ImageViewer = Tk.Label(topLeftFrame, image = blkImg)
        self.ImageViewer.image = blkImg
        self.ImageViewer.pack(side = "left", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        rightFrame = Tk.Frame(self, bg = "white")
        rightFrame.pack(side="right", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        self.alphaCount = 0
        self.betaCount = 0
        self.gammaCount = 0
        self.alphaText = Tk.StringVar()
        self.betaText = Tk.StringVar()
        self.gammaText = Tk.StringVar()

        self.alphaText.set("Alpha: 0")
        self.betaText.set("Beta: 0")
        self.gammaText.set("Gamma: 0")

        self.alpha = Tk.Label(rightFrame, textvariable = self.alphaText, bg = "white")
        self.alpha.pack(side="top", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.beta = Tk.Label(rightFrame, textvariable = self.betaText, bg = "white")
        self.beta.pack(side="top", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.gamma = Tk.Label(rightFrame, textvariable = self.gammaText, bg = "white")
        self.gamma.pack(side="top", padx = 5, pady = 5)

    def runSelectionChanged(self,*args):
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Public\dbsDetectorBookingSystem.accdb')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT RunFilePath, RunID FROM tblRuns")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            if row.RunFilePath == self.varRun.get():
                chosenRunID = row.RunID

        cursor.execute("SELECT LocalFilePath FROM tblFrames WHERE RunID=?") (chosenRunID)
        self.userFrames = cursor.fetchall()
        for frame in self.userFrames:
            self.Frames.append(frame)
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve]

Comment: What is happening that is different than you expect? Do you get an error? If so, what error? If not, what is happening that you don't expect?

Comment: the runsSelectionChanged routine does not run when varRuns is changed via selecting an option from the menu. The code that is there contains little which is irrelevant to a solution as far as I know.